# Reflecting over the Page_Load method returns null

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, postback

My question is related to retrieving attributes over a method which is called as part of a delegate _[e.g. Page.OnLoad or a Button_Click]_

I have a method attribute *[MyMethodAttribute(PropertyOne, PropertyTwo)]* over the _[Page_Load]_ or _[AnyWebControl_Event]_. This method attribute needs to be queried at runtime over the method on which it was placed. The method resides in the code-behind of any web page. All web pages derive from *BaseWebPage*. The event can be either a page load or a post back event.
Based on whether the event was triggered by Page Load or a postback, I get a handle to the control [a page, or the postback] and add my method [MyMethod] to be executed.

```
_eventControl = GetPostBackControl(page); //__EVENTTARGET or any control
    if (_eventControl != null) // this is a postback control for any page
    {
        _eventControl.Load += new EventHandler(MyMethod);
    }
    else // this is PageLoad method for any page
    {
        _eventControl = page;
        page.Load += new EventHandler(MyMethod);
    }
```

After which, I am trying to find the event [e.g. Page_Load] which triggered the page load. This is where I am not able to get a handle to the method and tried all different ways around it.

One of the ways was to query which event delegate triggered the load or postback. But the event cannot be accessed from outside of the class, so I am not able to use *MyDelegate.GetInvocationList()* as this returns null.

Any help is appreciated.

---

After some more effort, I have found that __EVENTARGUMENT will provide me the method name.
I have a different issue now. When I reflect over the ASPX page for the Page_Load method, it returns null.
Any ideas?

---

Page_load is a protected method and I was using Public BindingFlags. So after using NonPublic | Instance flag I am able to get to the Page_Load method with relfection

Comment: I found the answer to my issue. The Page_Load method is protected and I was using the Public binding flag. My issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more effort, I have found that __EVENTARGUMENT will provide me the method name.

---

Page_load is a protected method and I was using Public BindingFlags. So after using NonPublic | Instance flag I am able to get to the Page_Load method with relfection

Answer (score 0):

What about Page.IsPostback? If IsPostback is false then the the page load was not triggered by a postback and is a fresh load.

Comment: IsPostback will provide information whether it is postback. But it will not provide information about which control and whioh event. I found that just like __EVENTTARGET, I can find the Event name using __EVENTARGUMENT. So I have found the answer partially.